# Not able to add object to non-primitive array

Tags: java, arrays

this is test class.
here I'm trying to add string to string array. I cannot use ArrayList here in my case. So please give me a solution.

```
public class Test {

String[] name = new String[10];

public void addName(String sName){
    for(String s : name){
        if(s==null){
            s = sName;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void displayString(){
    for(String s : name){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}
```

this is main class

```
public class TestDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.addName("prasad");
    t.addName("ravi");
    t.addName("john");

    t.displayString();
}

}
```

the out put to displayString is null

Comment: The culprit is `s = sName;` this assignment does not do what you think it does. This assigns the value of `sName` to `s` but `s` is just a local variable; it does not tie to any element in the array `name`. As pointed out by others, you need to explicitly assign the element in `name` array by accessing it with `name[i] = sName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of s as a variable to which the **value** of name[index] is copied. Assigning a value to s would not change the value of name[index].

Try:

```
public void addName(String sName){
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        if (name[i] == null) {
            name[i] = sName;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya thanks for the answer and explanation. Many answers were correct. But you were faster. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`s = sName` assigns the value to the local variable, which used to hold the same value as the Nth member of the array, but uses a different place in the memory.
Long story short, when `s` is updated, the array element is not.

Try this:

```
public void addName(String sName){
    for(int i= 0; i < name.length; i++){
        if(name[i]==null){
            name[i] = sName;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya thank you for the answer and explanation. Will check it

Answer (score 1):

Someting like this should work

```
public void addName(String sName){
    for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
        if(name[i]==null){
           name[i] = sName;
           break;
        }
   }
```

}